# How to store django objects as session variables ( object is not JSON serializable)?

Tags: python, django

I have a simple view

```
def foo(request):
   card = Card.objects.latest(datetime)
   request.session['card']=card
```

For the above code I get the error

```
"<Card: Card object> is not JSON serializable"
```

Django version 1.6.2. What am I doing wrong ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Martijn is or might be the correct way to save the object in session variables.

But the issue was solved by moving back to Django 1.5. So this issue is specifically for django 1.6.2.

Hope this helps.

Comment: You could use the [PickleSerializer](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/http/sessions/#django.contrib.sessions.serializers.PickleSerializer) which was the default for Django 1.5. You would have to change the [SESSION_SERIALIZE](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/settings/#std:setting-SESSION_SERIALIZER) in your `settings.py`.

Comment: @akash-deshpande How did you store an object in session variables?

Comment: There is a very good reason why Django made this change: because using pickles has security implications. You generally don't want to use pickle for session data.

Answer (score 24):

In a session, I'd just store the object primary key:

```
request.session['card'] = card.id
```

and when loading the card from the session, obtain the card again with:

```
try:
    card = Card.objects.get(id=request.session['card'])
except (KeyError, Card.DoesNotExist):
    card = None
```

which will set `card` to `None` if there isn't a `card` entry in the session or the specific card doesn't exist.

By default, session data is [serialised to JSON](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/topics/http/sessions/#session-serialization). You could also [provide your own serializer](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/topics/http/sessions/#custom-serializers), which knows how to store the `card.id` value or some other representation and, on deserialization, produce your `Card` instance again.

Comment: Session variables are not cookies...(?)

Comment: @alias51: I was assuming that a cookie-based session was used, I think. 2014 is too long ago to be certain, but it doesn't really matter here.

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately the suggested answer does not work if the object is not a database object but some other kind of object - say, datetime or an object class Foo(object): pass that isn't a database model object.

Sure, if the object happen to have some id field you can store the id field in the database and look up the value from there but in general it may not have such a simple value and the only way is to convert the data to string in such a way that you can read that string and reconstruct the object based on the information in the string.

In the case of a datetime object this is made more complicated by the fact that while a naive datetime object can print out format %Z by simply not printing anything, the strptime object cannot read format %Z if there is nothing, it will choke unless there is a valid timezone specification there - so if you have a datetime object that may or may not contain a tzinfo field you really have to do strptime twice once with %Z and then if it chokes without the %Z. This is silly. It is made even sillier by the fact that datetime objects have a fromtimestamp function but no totimestamp function that uniformly produces a timestamp that fromtimestamp will read. If there is a format code that produces timestamp number I haven't found one and again, strftime/strptime suffer from the fact that they are not symmetric as described above.

Answer (score 3):

There are two simple ways to do this.

- If each object belongs to a single session at the same time, store session id as a model field, and update models.
- If an object can belong to multiple sessions at the same time, store object.id as a session variable.

Answer (score 0):

**--> DON'T EVER FEEL LIKE DOING SOMETHING LIKE THIS! <--**
Django using **session** and **ctypes**: Plz read [Martijn Pieters](https://stackoverflow.com/users/100297/martijn-pieters) explanation comment below.

```
class MyObject:
  def stuff(self):
    return "stuff..."

my_obj = MyObject()
request.session['id_my_obj'] = id(my_obj)

...

id_my_obj = request.session.get('id_my_obj')

import ctypes
obj = ctypes.cast(id_my_obj, ctypes.py_object).value

print(obj.stuff())    
# returns "stuff..."
```

Comment: ***DON'T EVER DO THIS***. This is a **monumentally Bad Idea**. If you are hosting Django in a multiprocess or multi-machine setup or let `my_obj` be garbage collected, this will not only not work, but **WILL** lead to memory corruption. `id(my_obj)` can *easily* point to an arbitrary piece of memory that is already used by something else, but the moment `ctypes.cast().value` is used Python will try to update the reference count for that 'object' and so start writing to that piece of memory.

Answer (score 0):

Objects cannot be stored in session from Django 1.6 or above.
If you don't want to change the behavior of the cookie value(of a object), you can add a dictionary there. This can be used for non database objects like class object etc.

```
from django.core.serializers.json import DjangoJSONEncoder
import json     
card_dict = card.__dict__
card_dict .pop('_state', None) #Pop which are not json serialize
card_dict = json.dumps(card_dict , cls=DjangoJSONEncoder)
request.session['card'] = card_dict
```

Hope it will help you!

Comment: They can, if you provide a custom serializer. Don't do this manually, configure [`SESSION_SERIALIZER`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/settings/#std:setting-SESSION_SERIALIZER) instead.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, as the object is not serializable (selenium webdriver), I had to use global variables, which is working great.

Comment: I have a ssh client object , can I store it to session so I can use anywhere in the project?