# Can't store a Selenium web driver object to recover it through Django views

Tags: python, django, selenium, session, store

After days of research, I wasn't able to properly store a Selenium web driver object to recover it through different Django views. In fact, My project has only one view, and all I need is to recover the same instance of the web driver object every time that view is called. All my app does is making AJAX post requests to the view and updating the frontend and some data in the web driver window.
Having initialized the driver as
`driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=driverpath, desired_capabilities=caps)` ,
these are all the things that I tried:

**1) Storing the object in request.session array.** Of course this doesn't work, a web driver object is to complex to be JSON serialized.
`TypeError: Object of type WebDriver is not JSON serializable`

**2) Pickle Serialize**: Didn't work.
A code like  `pickle.dumps(driver, open( "driver.p", "wb" ))` throws this error `AttributeError: Can't pickle local object '_createenviron.<locals>.encode'`

**3) Creating a new driver and assigning to its session_id attribute the previous web driver session_id value.** Didn't work. This was the approach:

```
   request.session['driver_id'] = driver.session_id
   #And then on another view call:
   chrome_options = Options()
   chrome_options.add_argument("--headless") #to prevent opening a new window
   new_driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=chrome_options)
   new_driver.session_id = request.session['driver_id']
```

**4) Using Ctypes:** This is the only solution that **works some of the times**, therefore the only solution that lets me use my project. As answered on [This Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22294788/how-to-store-django-objects-as-session-variables-object-is-not-json-serializab) by [Slipstream](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1866389/slipstream), this would be the approach:

```
import ctypes
request.session['id_my_obj'] = id(driver)
id_my_obj = request.session.get('id_my_obj')
obj = ctypes.cast(id_my_obj, ctypes.py_object).value
```

As [Martijn Pieters](https://stackoverflow.com/users/100297/martijn-pieters) said on that answer,

> "this is a monumentally Bad Idea. If you are hosting Django in a
> multiprocess or multi-machine setup or let my_obj be garbage
> collected, this will not only not work, but WILL lead to memory
> corruption."

I'm pretty sure that this is the reason why it fails and even crashes django sometimes. But sadly this is the only workaround.

My question is, is there a proper way to serialize a Selenium web driver object, or at least store it in a file or in any way that can be recoverable later?
Since the ctypes solution is the only one that works, is there a way to improve it to make it work everytime? I don't mind security implications since this is only for local use.

Python version: 3.8.5
Django version: 3.1.1
Selenium version: 4.0.0a1

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I was in the same boat. The best solution that worked great for me was to use global variables.

In this case, before creating the web driver object, just call "global driver" on each view that you need that same object.

So, I would do this way:

```
global driver
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=driverpath, desired_capabilities=caps)
```

On any other view in your views.py file, just call the "global driver" again and use the same object instance already instantiated before.